# why const char *pt2={'1', '2', '3', '\0'}; can't compile?

Tags: c++, string

```
const char *pt1="123";
const char *pt2={'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

Is it the same? The latter fails to compile.

> error: scalar object ‘pt2’ requires one element in initializer

Why? Isn't `"123"` the same as `{'1', '2', '3', '\0'}`?

Can I use `delete[] pt1` to release the resource or just `delete pt1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, they are not same. The first is a string literal, the second is an initializer list with elements of type `char`.

You can use second syntax like this:

```
const char pt2[]={'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

But even in this case, they are **not same**:

```
const char *pt1="123";
```

In this case `"123"` will be stored in read only memory. `pt1` just points to it.

```
const char pt2[]={'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

But in this all elements will be copied into pt2.

> can use delete [] pt1 to release resource or just delete pt?

**No you can't**

*(Aclually, it is possible, but you **should not do it**)*

Comment: hwo to understand string literal? isn't it a char array?

Comment: by using the syntax "123" you are creating a **specific** char array, stored in read only mem

Comment: @jiafu A string literal is a string literal. It's a literal which has type "array of *n* `const char`." As such, it can be converted to a pointer to `const char`. The `{}` syntax is an initialiser list, and performs aggregate initialisation of the variable being declared. It's not an array, so it cannot be converted to a pointer.

Comment: is there no need to delete pt1?

Comment: @jiafu, No. (4 more characters)

Comment: Are you `delet`ing every pointer? This memory was not dynamically allocated, so, you have no reasons to `delete` it.

Comment: do you mean the pointer pt isn't dynamically allocated? but if not delete it, how to recycle the space for literal string?

Comment: No, not _pointer_, but _memory_. You can allocate memory with `new`, but you do not use it in your code. So, you do not need to `delete` it.

Comment: @soon: not "*need*": "**have**". That's not an option.

Answer (score 4):

There no way to do it in C++. And no, your attempt to use aggregate initializer is not the same as string literal. Agggregate initializer like `{'1', '2', '3', '\0'}` does not introduce an array.

As a side note, in C language in order to implement an array object through a non-string literal you have to use C99 feature called *compound literals* using the following syntax

```
const char *pt2 = (const char []) {'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

This is pretty much the same as what you get with string literal. There is one difference though: string literal always has static storage duration, while compound literals used locally will have automatic storage duration.

Comment: The compound literal in C, is it stored in the read-only section of the binary (like string literals) or copied during runtime (like `pt2` in "soon"'s answer)?

Comment: @leemes: When it is used locally, it produces a local object, which means that it has to be built at run time. How it is build - by copying from read only memory or by initializing it in-place piece-by-piece - is an implementation detail. So yes, it should be virtually the same as in soon's answer.

Comment: Interesting information Andrey. Thanks for including it, even if it is C rather than C++.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because you're declaring a pointer, not an array. A pointer is a scalar type and therefore initializer lists with more than one element cannot be assigned to it.

You're probably confusing this with:

```
const char pt2[] = {'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

Which is not the same.

Comment: What about `const char tmp[] = {'1', '2', '3', '\0'}; const char *pt2 = tmp;`, is it the same as `pt1`, i.e. a pointer to a read-only memory *not* copied during runtime?

Comment: @leemes `tmp` is equivalent to `&tmp[0]`, so `pt2 = tmp` makes `pt2` point to `tmp[0]`.

Comment: This is obvious, but what I meant is: Is the array content copied/initialized into `tmp` or is `tmp` itself just a pointer into the read-only section of the program, like string literals are? I.e. is it `O(1)` to initialize `tmp`?

Comment: @leemes Since it's `const`, a copy can be avoided. But I assume this is up to the compiler. Inspecting the generated assembly shows that with optimizations turned off, GCC and Clang don't copy, while Intel C++ does. With optimizations enabled, Intel C++ doesn't copy either.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *pt2={'1', '2', '3', '\0'};
```

The language does not allow pointers to be initialised using an initialiser list, A pointer requires a memory address to be stored in it. The initialiser list does not return any memory address.

```
const char *pt1="123";
```

This is a *string literal* which has been defined in the language to be allocated on a Read only data segment and automatically terminated by `\0`. `ptr` is a pointer to `char` and can point to an array of `char` or single `char` for the matter. Since, `""` defined literals are confirmed to end with `\0` which acts as a indicator to end of string you can do that.